# What should letsencrypt certbot-auto's "webroot-path" be for a non-PHP / non-static-files website?

Tags: node.js, apache, flask, lets-encrypt, certbot

In the case you have a website using Apache only (maybe with PHP) that is in:

```
/home/www/mywebsite/
/home/www/mywebsite/index.php
/home/www/mywebsite/style.css
```

then, it's easy to set `certbot`'s `--webroot-path`:

```
./certbot-auto certonly --webroot --webroot-path /home/www/mywebsite/
                        --domain example.com --domain www.example.com --email a@example.com
```

---

**Question**: when using a website run by NodeJS
 or Python Flask or Bottle, linked to Apache either with WSGI (mod_wsgi) or simple proxying (I know the latter is not recommended in the case Python)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:5000/$1 [P,L]
```

**what should `--webroot-path` be?**

More specifically, if we have:

```
/home/www/mywebsite/       (Pyton example)
/home/www/mywebsite/myapp.py
/home/www/mywebsite/myapp.sqlite
/home/www/mywebsite/static/style.css
...
```

or

```
/home/www/mywebsite/        (NodeJS example)
/home/www/mywebsite/myapp.js
/home/www/mywebsite/myapp.sqlite
/home/www/mywebsite/static/style.css
...
```

then it doesn't make sense to choose `--webroot-path` as `/home/www/mywebsite/`, right?

Indeed, I don't want any other program/script like letsencrypt certbot to fiddle with my .py files.

Anyway, what does `--webroot-path` in `certbot` do? Will files there be analyzed, parsed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very interesting question that yet has a trivial answer. The official documentation states:

> The webroot plugin works by creating a temporary file for each of your
>   requested domains in `${webroot-path}/.well-known/acme-challenge`. Then
>   the Let’s Encrypt validation server makes HTTP requests to validate
>   that the DNS for each requested domain resolves to the server running
>   certbot.

So it doesn't really matter for Certbot where your *actual* webroot really resides as long it's served under domain you're trying to obtain certificates for, and it's not really interested in what is your project/framework structure is.

In other words, certbot **does not require** access to your project's directory with source files.

For example, Apache configuration for any application on your server can have shared so-called webroot, and Certbot only requires `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` available as static directory where it can store challenge file on the server side that will be available for Certbot validation server:

```
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ "/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/"

<Directory "/var/www/html/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>
```

Same way it works for NGINX when setting for a particular server block configuration:

```
server {

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
    }

}
```

Both examples would work if certificate is then requested with:

```
certbot-auto certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/html -d domain.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked at the root of a PHP website for which I have used `certbot-auto` / Letsencrypt successfully a few days ago (e.g. `/home/www/mywebsite/`), but I don't find any `.well-known/acme-challenge` file there. I used `ls -la`, but I can't find them. How does this work?

Comment: It's really straightforward. When using the webroot method the Certbot client places a challenge response inside domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ which is used for validation. When validation is complete, challenge file is removed from the target directory.

Answer (score 5):

This is complementary information to DamagedOrganic's answer (full credit to him).

For `certbot` / Letsencrypt to **validate a certificate**, it has to be able to access a challenge/response URL like http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/B39sdfoyoesdf21-qksl2638761867648514.
For this reason, it will create a temporary file (deleted at the end, that's why you won't find it anymore after a successful `certbot`) named `.well-known/acme-challenge/B39sdfoyoesdf21-qksl2638761867648514` for example in the path given by `--webroot-path`. (Then Letsencrypt's servers will access the URL mentioned before in order to verify that everything is ok.).

Solution: Choose `--webroot-path` as **the directory where static files are served**. Example: if you have this structure:

```
/home/www/mywebsite/
/home/www/mywebsite/myapp.py
/home/www/mywebsite/myapp.sqlite
/home/www/mywebsite/static/style.css        # /static/ serves static files... 
/home/www/mywebsite/static/favicon.ico
...
```

then use

```
./certbot-auto certonly --webroot --webroot-path /home/www/mywebsite/static/
                        --domain example.com --domain www.example.com --email a@example.com
```

---

PS: this is a solution with Bottle (I think it would be similar with Flask):

```
@route('/.well-known/acme-challenge/<filename>')
def wellknown(filename):           # Letsencrypt certbot-auto
    return static_file(filename, root='./static/.well-known/acme-challenge')
```

Comment: An option if one wants to make an individual `/.well-known/` for every application served.

Comment: (The name for the temporary file in `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` is randomly generated on each run.)